# Hashing string to integer (no security needed)

Tags: php, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php hash form string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965304/php-hash-form-string-to-integer)

I am looking to hash a url like `http://example.com` to a integer hash, small in size preferably. I would like to know if there is any built-in php functions that can do that.

The purpose for this is for speed in my mysql database for other operations inside mysql when I am comparing this hashes.

Comment: Wouldn't adding indexes on the relevant columns in MySql be a better ID. That should normally give you the speedup you need.

Comment: @AVee The thing is that I will make a lot of compares with that url, the url being a char will be slower then an integer, so my idea was to hash the url and make the comparisons between the hashes in mysql.

Comment: @Jon A maximum length of 10 would be great.

Comment: The FNV hash (http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) may be what you want.

Comment: @rossum Thank you, this is perfect for me. For I even found a PHP implementation here http://code.google.com/p/boyanov/wiki/FNVHash